# File for type [path to generated java file] created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have written an `AnnotationProcessor` which scans the code for a certain annotation and generates a Java Class out of it. 
It basically does something like this:

```
  private Multimap<String, Element> elements;

 @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factory.class)) {

        elements.put(annotatedElement.getSimpleName());
    }

   generateCode(elements);
}
```

Just in case that it matters:
`generateCode()` will iterate over the `elements`, which is a multimap, and create for each key a class (key+SUFFIX is the name of the file I want to generate) with code created from information of  the list of elements (the value of the mulitimap for a certain key) associated with the key .

Obviously I will call `generateCode()` every round of annotation processing. Therefore, I will get an compile error that says that a file for the same name has already generated in a previous round.

What is the correct way to handle that? I thought it would be a good idea to collect all annotations and generate it the classes only in last round, like this:

```
  private Multimap<String, Element> elements;

 @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factory.class)) {

        elements.put(annotatedElement.getSimpleName());
    }

   if (roundEnv.processingOver()){
      generateCode(elements);
   }
}
```

This fixes the problem of generating the same file multiple time, but now I get the following warning:

Warning:java: File for type [path to generated java file] created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.

The javadoc states out that you should not generate code in last round.
When should I generate my files?

Additionally I also get this warning in IntelliJ 14 if I click on rebuild project:
Warning:Output path [path to generated java file] intersects with a source root. Only files that were created by build will be cleaned.

Comment: The warning indicates that the annotation processor will not look at your generated code anymore because you are already in the last round of processing. This could be a problem if your generated code does also have annotations to be processed (like `Factory.class in your example)

Comment: I do understand that, my question is how should I implement that correctly to make the warning dismiss. Should I keep track of files I have already generated to generating duplicated files? Is it possible that java source files for the same annotation are processed in two differend processing rounds? (I do not generate java code with annotations that need further process in my processor)

Comment: It is possible that the same annotation occurs in different rounds but not the same source files. Each source file is only processed once. So in the first round you'll see all annotations from the source files that are present at the beginning. As long as you don't generate code with more annotations to be processed, the second round is the last one and it will be called with an empty set of annotations. So if it is still possible in your case that the same class could be generated twice, I suggest that you keep manually track of the classes that you already created.

Comment: I see ... any idea how to do that? I can annotate any class with my annotation, and out of all annotated classes I want to generate a single java file (no containing any further annotation). So I have to wait unit last round to generate java file because only in this round im sure that I have collected all classes annotated with my annotation, right? Any hint?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that you need all classes processed before you can generate your code. My understanding so far was that you could generate your code during the processing rounds with the risk that classes could be generated twice. So, I think in your case it is legitimate to generate your code in the last round. The warning would still be there but it does not affect you since your generated code does not need to be processed. If you want to avoid that warning the only option I see is that you generate your code in the first round assuming that the second round is "empty".

Comment: We need a way to disable this warning. In many cases this is completely desired behavior, and we don't want these incorrect warnings cluttering up the build output, causing confusion, and and hiding real problems. There needs to be a way to suppress this warning.

Comment: @GarretWilson Can you please provide a minimum example to fix your issue quickly?

Comment: `if(roundEnvironment.processingOver()) { /*generate a class*/ }` produces this warning. I want to suppress that warning. Is there part of that that needs more explanation?

Comment: @GarretWilson Please provide mimimum reproducable codebase to fix this quickly.

Comment: @AnishB. Their use case is essentially the same as the OP (and note Garret is not the OP).

Answer (score 0):

In case that you generate SINGLE FILE for every KEY i suppose you just need to rework your code to something like this:
**WARN:** *pseudocode*

```java
 private Multimap<String, Element> elements;
 private Set<String> files = new HashSet<String>();

 @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factory.class)) {

        elements.put(annotatedElement.getSimpleName());
    }
    for (Element e : elements) {
       String file = resolveFile(e);
       if (files.contains(file)) continue;
       generateCodeForFile(file, e);
       files.add(file);
    }

}
```

Comment: "_I can annotate any class with my annotation, and out of all annotated classes I want to generate a single java file (no containing any further annotation). So I have to wait unit last round to generate java file because only in this round im sure that I have collected all classes annotated with my annotation, right?_" – [Comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886169/file-for-type-path-to-generated-java-file-created-in-the-last-round-will-not-b/77235530#comment44187902_27886169).